# Grunt watch throws NoMethodError

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I've read the grunt, sass, and compass documentation but can't find much about this error. I also saw another person with a similar error but it was due to syntax problems in their contrib.rb file, which I don't believe I have in my contrib.rb file.

Problem: I run the grunt watch task and get an error anytime I make a change to my sass (*.scss) files. 
The error reads as follows:

```
NoMethodError on line 264 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb: _
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
```

As a result, none of my sass files are processing to my css folder. I'm new to grunt and am admittedly a little overwhelmed with the amount of initial setup I've done. I'd love any advice as to how my files might be configured incorrectly or whether there might be an error with one of the versions of compass or sass as it relates to grunt (all are most recent non-beta versions).

Here is the text of my contrib.rb file:

```
require "susy"
css_dir = _/css
sass_dir = _/components/sass
javascripts_dir = _/js 
output_style = :compressed
```

My gruntfile.js :

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-compass');
grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
        files: {
            '_/js/script.js': ['_/components/js/*.js'] //tells grunt to track and compress any .js file found in components/js folder   
        } //files
      } // my_target
    }, // uglify
  compass: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            config: 'config.rb',
        force: true // <-- ???
        } //options
    } //dev
  }, //compass
  watch: {
    options: { livereload: true },
    scripts: {
        files: ['_/components/js/*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify']
    }, //scripts
    sass: {
        files: ['_/components/sass/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['compass:dev']
    }, //sass
    html: {
      files: ['*.html']
    }
   } // watch
  })// initConfig
 grunt.registerTask('default', 'watch'); //makes 'grunt' command automaticaly execute the watch command to monitor JS files
} //exports
```

And my project folder structure:

```
sass_first_proj
   |
   _(folder)
     |
     components
     |
     css
     |
     js
   images
   node_modules
     |
     grunt
     |
     grunt-contrib-compass
     |
     grunt-contrib-uglify
     |
     grunt-contrib-watch
     |
     matchdep

 .gitignore
 |
 config.rb
 |
 gruntfile.js
 |
 index.html
 |
 package.json
```

Comment: Are you able to just run `grunt compass` or do you get the same error? My guess is the problem is not with the `watch` task at all.

Comment: I'm generating the same error when I run grunt compass, and still haven't had any luck with getting the css file to link to the scss file.

Comment: Hmm... can you just run `compass` from the command line directly? I'm not sure exactly what the arguments are that you'll need. But if that doesn't run either then it may not be a problem with Grunt at all.

Comment: I'm able to run the compass watch task from the command line with no error messages, but when I change into my project directory (the root folder shown above as sass_first_proj)I generate the NoMethodError again.

Comment: I'm not talking about the Grunt task, I'm asking if you can run `compass` itself from the command line, outside of Grunt. We need to isolate the problem to either compass or the watch task. But with an error like that my guess is that it's a compass issue.

Comment: I ran '$ compass watch' from the command line while in my User directory (i.e. outside of my project folder and outside of grunt) and had no errors. Bash returned: 'Compass is polling for changes'. I'm not sure if this is what you mean by 'run compass itself from the command line', because I'm not sure if I can just "run" compass without having it applied to a project and attached to specific tasks.   It's strange that I get no errors running 'compass watch' from my Users directory but get the NoMethodError when I run the same command from the project that contains the compass files. Thanks!

Comment: That's close to what I mean, but you can actually initiate a compile action without using `watch` like so: `compass compile path/to/file.sass`. That will tell us if compass can compile your files or not, helping narrow down where the problem lies.

Comment: When I navigate to the sass folder, I get this message:

Comment: 'Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.'      Fair enough. When I point it to the specific file (and I've tried it with all the files that have any sass content in this folder), I get this message: 'You must compile individual stylesheets from the project directory.'  There _is_ code to compile here. I'm lost!

Comment: Apparently you need to provide both the path to the project and to the individual file. I'm guessing the project path is wherever the config file is, so maybe: `compass compile /project/root /project/root/_/components/sass/some-file.scss`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were able to solve this, but I was receiving the same error.

I had to include a forward slash before the directories to get Grunt to the right paths. I'm using similar steps in using Grunt and Compass for my project, and I'm on my PC so I just put the paths in single quotes. Based on how your project directory is structured, the two respective lines in the config.rb file would look like this:

```
css_dir = '/_/css'
sass_dir = '/_/components/sass'
```

Also in your question, I noticed you stated it was the "contrib.rb" file, but in your file directory that it is named config.rb. You reference it in your gruntfile.js file as config.rb, as well, but I just wanted to make sure that this file in the root of your project was being named "config.rb".

I know it was a lot of setup, so I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing, I've never used a contrib.rb file when using compass with Grunt. I know you can, and if you get it working, great. but the other option is to just specify the paths in the grunt config. Of course, this all assumes that you are able to actually compile the sass files. When googling for that error, it seems that much of the time it was an issue with the contrib.rb file that caused the issue.

So with that said, maybe you could leave off the `contrib.rb` file and just use Grunt?

```
compass: {
  dev: {
    options: {
      sassDir: "_/components/sass",
      specify: "_/components/sass/**/*.scss", // might not be necessary for you
      cssDir: "_/css",
      javascriptsPath: "_/js",
      outputStyle: "compressed",
      require: "susy"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Gave that a try and played around with a few more ideas I've have after looking at the gruntfile.js on github, but still no luck. I really appreciate all the help but think my best bet is to blow it all up and start over. If I come up with any solution, I'll post them here. Thanks again!

Comment: Argh... that's too bad. Feel free to post here if you find a solution, maybe we can get a side-by-side of the old and new to see what changed. Good luck.